# Struggling with passing the state object array which is initially is empty

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I try to pass the array of objects to table component to display it. The error I get is pretty logical, however I can't find a way to fix this issue. I marked a line with the problem I keep getting:

```
Type 'Expense[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Expense[] | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Expense[] | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Is there a way to avoid passing a null value or ignoring it if it is passed?

`App.tsx`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ExpenseList from "./ExpenseTacker/Components/ExpenseList/ExpenseList";
import ExpenseFilter from "./ExpenseTacker/Components/ExpenseFilter/ExpenseFilter";
import ExpenseForm from "./ExpenseTacker/Components/ExpenseForm/ExpenseForm";
import categories from "./ExpenseTacker/categories";

interface Expense {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  amount: number;
  category: string;
}

function App() {
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");
  const [expenses, setExpanses] = useState<Expense[] | null>(null);

  const visibleExpenses = selectedCategory
    ? expenses?.filter((e: Expense) => e.category === selectedCategory)
    : expenses;
  if (expenses === null) {
    return <div>The table is empty</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="mb-5">
          <ExpenseForm
            onSubmbit={(newExpense) =>
              setExpanses([
                ...(expenses || []),
                { ...newExpense, id: expenses.length + 1 },
              ])
            }
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <ExpenseFilter
            onSelectCategory={(category) => setSelectedCategory(category)}
          ></ExpenseFilter>
        </div>

        <ExpenseList
          expenses={visibleExpenses} //THE PROBLEM LINE
          onDelete={(id) => setExpanses(expenses.filter((e) => e.id != id))}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`ExpenseList.tsx` (table file):

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TbFileDescription } from "react-icons/tb";
import { RiMoneyDollarBoxLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import { MdOutlineCategory } from "react-icons/md";

interface Expense {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  amount: number;
  category: string;
}

interface Props {
  expenses?: Expense[];
  onDelete: (id: number) => void;
}

const ExpenseList = ({ expenses, onDelete }: Props) => {
  if (expenses?.length === 0) return null;
  return (
    <table className="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            <TbFileDescription/> Description
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <RiMoneyDollarBoxLine/> Amount
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <MdOutlineCategory/> Category
          </th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {expenses?.map((expense) => (
          <tr key={expense.id}>
            <td>{expense.description}</td>
            <td>{expense.amount}</td>
            <td>{expense.category}</td>
            <td>
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-danger"
                onClick={() => onDelete(expense.id)}
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Total</td>
          <td>
            $
            {expenses?.reduce((acc, expense) => expense.amount + acc, 0)
              .toFixed(2)}
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  );
};

export default ExpenseList;
```

Comment: `null` and `undefined` aren't the same. Pick one, and use it consistently.

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by picking and using. I initialized the array with null but still getting the error with 'undefined' type

Comment: Read the error message - in the parent you have `T | null`, in the child you have `?: T` which is basically `T | undefined`.

Comment: Well I get it. I just don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have error because `visibleExpenses` variable passed to ExpenseList component possible `null` value sometimes

you can fix with 3 solution:

1. change condition :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ExpenseList from "./ExpenseTacker/Components/ExpenseList/ExpenseList";
import ExpenseFilter from "./ExpenseTacker/Components/ExpenseFilter/ExpenseFilter";
import ExpenseForm from "./ExpenseTacker/Components/ExpenseForm/ExpenseForm";
import categories from "./ExpenseTacker/categories";

interface Expense {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  amount: number;
  category: string;
}

function App() {
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");
  const [expenses, setExpanses] = useState<Expense[] | null>(null);

  const visibleExpenses = selectedCategory
    ? expenses?.filter((e: Expense) => e.category === selectedCategory)
    : expenses;
  if (expenses === null || visibleExpenses === null) // => change this condition
  {
    return <div>The table is empty</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="mb-5">
          <ExpenseForm
            onSubmbit={(newExpense) =>
              setExpanses([
                ...(expenses || []),
                { ...newExpense, id: expenses.length + 1 },
              ])
            }
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <ExpenseFilter
            onSelectCategory={(category) => setSelectedCategory(category)}
          ></ExpenseFilter>
        </div>

        <ExpenseList
          expenses={visibleExpenses} //THE PROBLEM LINE
          onDelete={(id) => setExpanses(expenses.filter((e) => e.id != id))}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

2. Change type of Props of ExpectationList component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TbFileDescription } from "react-icons/tb";
import { RiMoneyDollarBoxLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import { MdOutlineCategory } from "react-icons/md";

interface Expense {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  amount: number;
  category: string;
}

interface Props {
  expenses?: Expense[] | null;
  onDelete: (id: number) => void;
}

const ExpenseList = ({ expenses = [], onDelete }: Props) => {
  if (expenses?.length === 0) return null;
  return (
    <table className="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            <TbFileDescription/> Description
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <RiMoneyDollarBoxLine/> Amount
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            <MdOutlineCategory/> Category
          </th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {expenses?.map((expense) => (
          <tr key={expense.id}>
            <td>{expense.description}</td>
            <td>{expense.amount}</td>
            <td>{expense.category}</td>
            <td>
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-danger"
                onClick={() => onDelete(expense.id)}
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Total</td>
          <td>
            $
            {expenses?.reduce((acc, expense) => expense.amount + acc, 0)
              .toFixed(2)}
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  );
};

export default ExpenseList;
```

3. Apply the above two methods together